# From a cmd script how to find if it was call from cmd console or via clicking explorer

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a script.

If call from cmd console, the error is displayed. However if call by clicking from explorer I want to pause it so the user has a chance to read the error before the window closes.

Is there a way to know wether the script was call from cmd console or from windows explorer?

Thanks,
Jes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `%cmdcmdline%` which will be something along the lines of

```
cmd /c ""C:\path\foo.cmd""
```

when started from Explorer.

In fact, unless your batch file runs `cmd` you should be able to rely on that the variable never contains the full path to the batch file unless started via the `open` verb (which is what Explorer does; but so do a few others, e.g. Far Manager or PowerShell).